# How to get the object array based on value of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I would like to know how to get the object array list based on values matching in javascript

If any of object value matches with parameter, then return that array in javascript.

```
var objarr = [
  {id:1, email: 'xyz@gmail.com', value: 10, name: 'ram'},
  {id:2, email: 'xyz@gmail.com', value: 20, name: 'Tom'},
  {id:3, email: 'ss@gmail.com', value: 30, name: 'Lucas'},
  {id:4, email: 'ct@gmail.com', value: 40, name: 'Chris'},
  {id:5, email: 'tam@gmail.com', value: 30, name: 'Lucas Tim'}
]

function getList(val){
  var result=[];
  var checkdata = objarr.filter(e=>{
   if(Object.values(e)===val){
    result.push(e);
  }
return result;
})
}
console.log(result);

Expected Output:
getList('xyz@gmail.com');
scenario 1: 
[
  {id:1, email: 'xyz@gmail.com', value: 10, name: 'ram'},
  {id:2, email: 'xyz@gmail.com', value: 20, name: 'Tom'}
]
scenario 2:
getList('Chris');
[
  {id:4, email: 'ct@gmail.com', value: 40, name: 'Chris'}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function should return either `true` or `false` depending on the search criteria.

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns an Array as output. To check whether a value is in an array, you can use [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

You should chck for value with `Object.values(e).includes(val)`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var objarr = [
  { id: 1, email: 'xyz@gmail.com', value: 10, name: 'ram' },
  { id: 2, email: 'xyz@gmail.com', value: 20, name: 'Tom' },
  { id: 3, email: 'ss@gmail.com', value: 30, name: 'Lucas' },
  { id: 4, email: 'ct@gmail.com', value: 40, name: 'Chris' },
  { id: 5, email: 'tam@gmail.com', value: 30, name: 'Lucas Tim' }
]

function getList(val) {
  var checkdata = objarr.filter(e => {
    if (Object.values(e).includes(val)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
  return checkdata;
}
console.log(getList('xyz@gmail.com'));
console.log(getList('Chris'));
```

**Simplified version**

```js
var objarr = [
  { id: 1, email: 'xyz@gmail.com', value: 10, name: 'ram' },
  { id: 2, email: 'xyz@gmail.com', value: 20, name: 'Tom' },
  { id: 3, email: 'ss@gmail.com', value: 30, name: 'Lucas' },
  { id: 4, email: 'ct@gmail.com', value: 40, name: 'Chris' },
  { id: 5, email: 'tam@gmail.com', value: 30, name: 'Lucas Tim' }
]

const getList = (val) => objarr.filter(e => Object.values(e).includes(val))
console.log(getList('xyz@gmail.com'));
console.log(getList('Chris'));
```

Comment: You could return `Object.values(e).includes(val)` directly, instead of using an if statement.

Comment: Added in the second snippet. First anippet followed the same approach of the user question

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get all the values of an object and then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to get the desired result.

**`ONE LINER`**

```
objarr.filter((o) => Object.values(o).some((v) => v === val));
```

```js
var objarr = [
  { id: 1, email: "xyz@gmail.com", value: 10, name: "ram" },
  { id: 2, email: "xyz@gmail.com", value: 20, name: "Tom" },
  { id: 3, email: "ss@gmail.com", value: 30, name: "Lucas" },
  { id: 4, email: "ct@gmail.com", value: 40, name: "Chris" },
  { id: 5, email: "tam@gmail.com", value: 30, name: "Lucas Tim" },
];

const getList = val => objarr.filter((o) => Object.values(o).some(v => v === val));

console.log(getList("xyz@gmail.com"));
console.log(getList("Chris"));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```